# Alarm in AWS when Storage gets full(Ec2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to create an Alarm in AWS which notifies me when my Storage used >= 80%

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/UseCloudWatchUnifiedAgent.html

Comment: Related https://serverfault.com/questions/267455/easiest-way-to-automatically-check-ec2-disk-space-and-be-alerted-if-it-is-runnin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has no visibility *inside* your Amazon EC2 instance. This is because the instance is run by the Operating System and AWS does not have a login to the instance.

However, you can [Collect metrics and logs from Amazon EC2 instances and on-premises servers with the CloudWatch agent - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html), which is a piece of software you install on the instance. It then runs *inside* the instance and sends metrics (such as available disk space) to Amazon CloudWatch. You can then **create an Alarm** on that metric to receive notification when the disk spaces metric passes a threshold.